# Hibernate Self Join

Tags: hibernate, join, self-join

**Background**

I have a table with columns *id, imageId, propertyId*.

There could be many images associated with a single property and there could be many properties associated with a single image.

`imageId - many-to-many - propertyId`

I have a list of propertyIds and I want to find out all the images associated with all the propertyIds **using Hibernate**.

**Problem.**

Just now I pick one property at a time and using the Criteria API find all the imageIds associated with this propertyId, I obtain a list of imageIds. I use this list of imageIds in the next query and say

`select imageIds where imageId in (imageIds obtained in previous step) where propertyId = x`

So effectively, the number of queries hitting the DB would equal to the number of propertyIds. I don't think this is a good solution, having to hit the database n times, I tried using Detached Query but did not succeed. Is there a better solution?

Also, when I finally obtain the list of imageIds, is it a good idea (let us not take into account the number of results) to store it in the user session and paginate OR is it a good idea to repeat the entire process OR shall I consider storing it in the DB all for the purpose of pagination?

Comment: @Shardul - What you've described IS a many-to-many relationship and thus is best mapped as one. If you want to avoid it, perhaps you should explain why and how are your entities mapped currently. It's hard to suggest anything without understanding your entity hierarchy first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a problem with your database schema:

You're trying to cram 3 separate associations (image - collection, image - property, collection - property) into a single *ImageCollection* table. This is not a good thing. While you could probably get away with this using plain SQL (at a cost of lots of rows with null columns in that table), you won't be able to properly map this in Hibernate. BTW, this table doesn't need a surrogate primary key.

What you need to do is split it into 3 separate tables and map your model as proper many-to-many in Hibernate. For example:

```
@Entity
public class Image {
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name="IMAGE_PROPERTIES",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="IMAGE_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PROPERTY_ID")
  )
  private Collection<Property> properties;

  ...
}
```

`IMAGE_PROPERTIES` table will only have `IMAGE_ID` and `PROPERTY_ID` columns; you will have `COLLECTION_IMAGES` and `COLLECTION_PROPERTIES` tables just like it as well.

You will then be able to query images by property names like:

```
from Image img
  left join img.properties as prop
  with prop.name in ('Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3')
```

If your properties are really like tags, take a look at [this article](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html) for AND / OR / UNION query examples.

If you properties are really properties (that is, they have the lifecycle of owner entity and can't belong to more than one entity at once), consider splitting them into two tables (one for Images and one for Collections) and using one-to-many associations. That way you won't be needing `IMAGE_PROPERTIES` and `COLLECTION_PROPERTIES` tables from above.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a class like this (Note: I did not write this with an ide, so the code may not be syntactically correct):

```
public class Property {
@ManyToMany
private List<Image> images;
}

public class Image {
@ManyToMany
private List<Property> properties;
}
```

So a query like `select property from Property property` should get you the list of properties, which you can get to through normal Java properties.

Is that what you're looking for, or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: You have understood it properly, but I am considering avoiding the ManyToMany relations. Is there an alternative?

Comment: When I say I want to avoid it, it is because the scenario is actually more complex, I have simplified it a bit and put it here..

Comment: Actually, it's not really all that complex, nor is it really that unique.